# How to connect to routers inside Eve-ng from host machine?

Tags: linux, networking, router, virtualization, vmware

I'm trying to learn Ansible using eve-ng, I only wanna test basic things first. So, I'm trying to ssh a router in eve-ng from the host machine.

What I've tried is I tried to make the interface request DHCP address while connected to pnet0 (Management Interface). The interface actually gets its DHCP address that is the same as my home network. The leased address is even in my home router's leased DHCP addresses table. However, eve-ng is acting like a firewall between the two. Both the host device and eve-ng can ping each other. Likewise, eve-ng and the virtual router can ping each other. But host and the virtual-router cannot ping each other. I've even disabled ufw on eve-ng but still no luck.

Is there a way to make eve-ng route? I do know eve-ng is based on Ubuntu but I'm not adept in configuring routes and firewalls on Linuxes yet